# MediaPlayer doesn't play selected tune on Samsung devices

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-permissions, android-cursor, mediastore

I have an alarm clock app. User is allowed to choose a ringtone from: device ringtones, app alarm tones, their own music. Whatever tone user chooses the MediaPlayer plays the default tone, not the selected one. The problem only occurs on Samsung devices.

When user wants to change alarm tone I ask for the permission:

```
 alarmToneLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                int currentAPIVersion = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
                if (currentAPIVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(AlarmEditActivity.this,
                            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(AlarmEditActivity.this, new String[]{
                                    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 31);

                    } else {
                        showAlarmToneDialog();
                    }
                } else {
                    showAlarmToneDialog();
                }
            }
        });

 @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 31:
                    showAlarmToneDialog();
                break;
            default:
                super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
```

And I have  in manifest.

This is how I get all the music on a user's device. I show it as a list of radio buttons. When the user chooses one of them then String uriForTheSong gets saved.

```
  private TreeMap<String,String> getAllMusic(){
        ContentResolver cr = this.getActivity().getContentResolver();
        TreeMap<String, String> listOfAllSongsWithUri = new TreeMap<>();

        String[] projection = {
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM
        };

        Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + "!= 0";
        String sortOrder = MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + " ASC";

        Cursor cursor = cr.query(uri, projection, selection, null, sortOrder);

        int count = 0;

        if(cursor != null)
        {
            count = cursor.getCount();

            if(count > 0)
            {
                while(cursor.moveToNext())
                {
                    String uriOfTheSong = cursor.getString(0);
                    String nameOfTheSong = cursor.getString(1);
                    listOfAllSongsWithUri.put(nameOfTheSong, uriOfTheSong);
                }

            }
        }

        cursor.close();
        return listOfAllSongsWithUri;
    }
```

When it is time for alarm to ring the AlarmToneActivity starts and plays the tone. If an exception occurs MediaPlayer uses the default uri (AMAZING_GRACE_URI)

```
      void playSound(Context context, String alarmToneUriString) throws IllegalArgumentException,
            SecurityException,
            IllegalStateException,
            IOException {

        Uri alarmToneUri = Uri.parse(alarmToneUriString);
        try {
            mPlayer.setDataSource(context, alarmToneUri);
        } catch (Exception e){
            alarmToneUri = Uri.parse(AMAZING_GRACE_URI);
            mPlayer.setDataSource(context, alarmToneUri);
        }
        AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

        if (audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM) != 0) {
            if(SharedPref.getGradualVolumeSetting()){
                audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM, audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM), 0);
            }
            playerStart();
        }
    }


    void playerStart(){
        try {
            mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
            mPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mPlayer) {
                    mPlayer.start();
                }
            });
            mPlayer.prepareAsync();
            mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                    mPlayer.start(); 
                }
            });
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        }
    }
```

I don't have a Samsung phone so I can't check what exception occurs.

Comment: Does crashlytics shows any error?

Comment: no. It was reported by a few of the app's users.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see it in Your Code. Have you checked the life cycle of the media Player ([here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer))?
reset Mediaplayer before `setDatasource`.

Comment: Yes I do. I don't see how that would matter. The problem is that the wrong ringtone is playing (the default one instead of the one the user chose). What I think happens is that one of the exceptions gets thrown (IllegalArgumentException, SecurityException, IllegalStateException, IOException)

Comment: because your media player could not release the played file and therefore you could not switch to a new audio file. As @GGK wrote, try to catch the error (which You suspect) with `Crashlytics.log`